# React module federation micro frontend- webpack 5 public path auto is not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

In my react micro frontend project which uses module federation plugin `remoteEntry.js` path is incorrectly fetched and application crashes.

With hard-coded `publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/"` in webpack things work as expected.

But due to existing CI/CD setup in my project, `publicPath` in the webpack config cannot be hard-coded at the build time.

As per various articles it was recommended to use `publicPath : auto` in the webpack config of the application.

Yes `publicPath : auto` solves the issue of hard coding at build time.

But during page refresh, `remoteEntry.js` is fetched from incorrect url.

To simulate the scenario I created simple react application using webpack and module federation plugin

On the initial load `remoteEntry.js` is fetched from `http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js` as expected

[image]

When under nested URL `http://localhost:3000/home/foo/about`, On refresh `main.js` and `remoteEntry.js` is fetched from **`http://localhost:3000/home/foo/remoteEntry.js`** - application crashes

[image]

Github link for the project simulating the scenario
https://github.com/cyberfury10/mf-page-refresh-issue

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "auto",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "mf_page_refresh_issue",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        './Component' : './src/test-component.js'
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

I am using `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"` and also tried with `"@reach/router": "^1.3.4",` but the issue is same

Tried solutions given in https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/102 but it didn't work

Last suggestion from **ScriptedAlchemy**  in the above link is to use `publicPath : auto` in 2022

Any help would much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, add another `publicPath : '/'` in HtmlWebpackPlugin().

something like the following

```
  new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: './public/index.html',
    favicon: './public/favicon.png',
    assets: './public/assets',
    publicPath: '/',
  }),
```

Referred workaround from the following link and it helped
https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/pull/2170